# Reference an Object in a Method

Tags: c#

How do I reference the student object created in the first button in my method below? I thought I could simply do "ref object student" but when I do it won't let me use any of the methods associated with the student class and simply says "object does not contain a definition for . . ."

Button:

```
private void addStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add Student Button
    {
        string name = nameBox.Text;
        string course = courseBox.Text;
        bool NumTrue = true;
        decimal asgnScore;
        decimal mScore;
        decimal fScore;
        decimal itMJR; //IT Major Check

        student = new Student(name);
        student.SetCourse(course);

        VerifyNums(ref NumTrue, out asgnScore, out mScore, out fScore);

        if (NumTrue)
        {
            student.Assignment = asgnScore;
            student.Midterm = mScore;
            student.final = fScore;
            AddPoints(out itMJR);
            clearButton_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            BadInput();
        }
    }
```

Method:

```
 private void CalculateGrades(ref object student, out decimal averageExamScore, out   decimal percentGrade, ref decimal AW, ref decimal TW, ref decimal itMJR)
    {

        asgnScore = ((asgnScore + itMJR) * AW);

        name = nameBox.Text; course = courseBox.Text;
        averageExamScore = (((fScore + itMJR) + (mScore + itMJR)) / 2);
        averageExamScore = averageExamScore * TW;
        percentGrade = averageExamScore + asgnScore;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of `ref object student`:

```
ref Student student
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I've been freaking out over that for an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ref](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ref)

```
ref Student student
```

> Ref parameters are changed at the calling site. They are passed as
>   references, not values. This means you can assign the parameter in the
>   called method and have it also be assigned at the calling site.